# How do I get rid of these white boxes left and right of the container?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

So I have this WebSocket Chat and I get these white boxes left and right to it if I apply a background-color to it. How do I get rid of them? I have had this problem with a few of my pages...

I tried adding a background-color to the html, body and also container tag but they still stay white. Maybe it has something to do with bootstrap?

Here is the code:

Chat.ejs:

```html
<div class="container">
    <h1 class="text-center mb-4">WebSocket Chat</h1>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" value=""/>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="saveName()"> Set Name </button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="sendMyMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <div class="row btn-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/">Go back to the start page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
html, body{
    background-color: #222531;
}

.container {
    background-color: #222531;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;

}

.form-control {
    background-color: #2e3440;
    color: white;
    border-color: #4c566a;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-color: #81a1c1;
    border-color: #81a1c1;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #5e81ac;
    border-color: #5e81ac;
}

/* Chat styles */
.message {
    background-color: white;
    color: #222531;
    padding-left: 10px;
    /*border-radius: 5px;*/
}

.message:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

a {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 30%;
}
```

Here is a link to see it live in action: [JSFiddle Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/xtahvjb6/)

Comment: Your background rule is being overridden by Bootstrap's. You can try using the dreaded `!important` on your rule, or give your body and ID or class and target that instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background-color doesn't change because you're including the `bootstra.css` styles that overwrite yours. So there are three options:

1. Use `!important` (NOT recommended!)
2. Use a "more specific" CSS-Selector (i.e., `div.myClass` is more specific than `.myClass`). However, this is not that applicable here.
3. Your best choice: Use another wrapping container around your "div-container".

### Edit

Also note, that you can see that yourself when using the `Debugger` tools of your browser. The following image shows an example where you can see, that your styles are overwritten by something.

[image: Style Overwritten]

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
ws.onopen = function() {
  console.log('websocket is connected ...')
  ws.send('connected')
}
ws.onmessage = function(ev) {
  console.log(ev);
  addTextMessage(ev.data);
}

function sendMyMessage() {
  let text = document.getElementById("text").value;
  ws.send(text);
  // Clear the input field
  document.getElementById("text").value = "";
}

function addTextMessage(message) {
  const tag = document.createElement("div");
  tag.classList.add("message");
  const username = localStorage.getItem("username");
  const text = document.createTextNode(
    username ? `${username}: ${message}` : message
  );
  tag.appendChild(text);
  const element = document.getElementById("messages");
  element.appendChild(tag);
}

function saveName() {
  const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
  if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem("username", name);
  }
}

const input = document.getElementById("text");
input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
  if (event.key == "Enter") {
    console.log('enter pressed');
    event.preventDefault();
    sendMyMessage();
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background-color: #222531;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: #222531;
}

.container {
  background-color: #222531;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
  color: white;
}

.form-control {
  background-color: #2e3440;
  color: white;
  border-color: #4c566a;
}

.btn-primary {
  background-color: #81a1c1;
  border-color: #81a1c1;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
  background-color: #5e81ac;
  border-color: #5e81ac;
}


/* Chat styles */

.message {
  background-color: white;
  color: #222531;
  padding-left: 10px;
  /*border-radius: 5px;*/
}

.message:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

a {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>WebSocket Chat</title>
  <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="/css/chat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <!-- ADDED -->
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="text-center mb-4">WebSocket Chat</h1>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your name" value="" />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="saveName()">
            Set Name
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="sendMyMessage()">Send</button>
      </div>
      <div id="messages"></div>
      <div class="row btn-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/">Go back to the start page</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ADDED -->
  <!-- Add Bootstrap JS (required for some components to work) -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1ZaXMtZwzTQcn+E3r/3b9MFsN/0oV7NcM1CbdKjzAsZcdYBv7zBkaP8fDPQjgsmh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.container` which is adding a `max-width:960px` and your background colour is white, creating the two white strips either side.

You have two options:

1. You can either change `.container` to `.container-fluid`, which will make it the full width of the page.
2. Or add a main wrapper to control the background colour of that section and then set the container within that to keep the same width.

```js
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
        ws.onopen = function () {
            console.log('websocket is connected ...')
            ws.send('connected')
        }
        ws.onmessage = function (ev) {
            console.log(ev);
            addTextMessage(ev.data);
        }
        function sendMyMessage() {
            let text = document.getElementById("text").value;
            ws.send(text);
            // Clear the input field
            document.getElementById("text").value = "";
        }

        function addTextMessage(message) {
            const tag = document.createElement("div");
            tag.classList.add("message");
            const username = localStorage.getItem("username");
            const text = document.createTextNode(
                username ? `${username}: ${message}` : message
            );
            tag.appendChild(text);
            const element = document.getElementById("messages");
            element.appendChild(tag);
        }

        function saveName() {
            const name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                localStorage.setItem("username", name);
            }
        }

        const input = document.getElementById("text");
        input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
            if (event.key == "Enter") {
                console.log('enter pressed');
                event.preventDefault();
                sendMyMessage();
            }
        });
```

```css
html, body{
    background-color: #222531;
}

.main-wrapper {
    background-color: #222531;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: white;

}

.form-control {
    background-color: #2e3440;
    color: white;
    border-color: #4c566a;
}

.btn-primary {
    background-color: #81a1c1;
    border-color: #81a1c1;
}

.btn-primary:hover {
    background-color: #5e81ac;
    border-color: #5e81ac;
}

/* Chat styles */
.message {
    background-color: white;
    color: #222531;
    padding-left: 10px;
    /*border-radius: 5px;*/
}

.message:last-of-type {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

a {
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>WebSocket Chat</title>
    <!-- Add Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="/css/chat.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-aFq/bzH65dt+w6FI2ooMVUpc+21e0SRygnTpmBvdBgSdnuTN7QbdgL+OapgHtvPp" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-wrapper">


<div class="container ">
    <h1 class="text-center mb-4">WebSocket Chat</h1>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input
                id="name"
                type="text"
                class="form-control"
                placeholder="Enter your name"
                value=""
        />
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="saveName()">
            Set Name
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3">
        <input id="text" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your message">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" onclick="sendMyMessage()">Send</button>
    </div>
    <div id="messages"></div>
    <div class="row btn-container">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="/">Go back to the start page</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- Add Bootstrap JS (required for some components to work) -->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-1ZaXMtZwzTQcn+E3r/3b9MFsN/0oV7NcM1CbdKjzAsZcdYBv7zBkaP8fDPQjgsmh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```